# How to call model in UpgradeData Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade-script

i have a model that i can be called via controller like this

```
    protected $_sync;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Lime\Hello\Model\SyncFactory $sync)
    {
        $this->_sync = $sync;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

but when i try to call it in upgrade data it gives me an error like this :

> Upgrading data.. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Lime\Courier\Model\SyncFactory::syncAll()

here's my upgrade data:

```
namespace Lime\Courier\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
      protected $_sync;
      public function __construct(\Lime\Courier\Model\SyncFactory $sync)
      {
          $this->_sync = $sync;
      }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {


        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            //code to upgrade to 1.0.1
            $run = $this->_sync;
            $run->syncAll();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

this is the function in the model

```
public function syncAll(){
    $this->setProvinces();
    $this->setCities();
    $this->setCouriers();
    $this->setCourierservices();
  }
```

Comment: Have you check factory class is exist or not ? have you run `setup:di:compile` command to generate factory ?

Comment: you can try with $run = $this->_sync->create(); $run->syncAll();

Comment: @IdhamChoudry I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try with,

```
$run = $this->_sync->create(); $run->syncAll();
```

namespace Lime\Courier\Setup;

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
      protected $_sync;
      public function __construct(\Lime\Courier\Model\SyncFactory $sync)
      {
          $this->_sync = $sync;
      }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {


        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            //code to upgrade to 1.0.1
            $run = $this->_sync->create();
            $run->syncAll();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```